# Calculating Percentiles on the fly

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics

I'm programming in Java. Every 100 ms my program gets a new number.

It has a cache with contains the history of the last `n = 180` numbers.
When I get a new number `x` I want to calculate how many numbers there are in the cache which are smaller than `x`. 
Afterwards I want to delete the oldest number in the cache.

Every 100 ms I want to repeat the process of calculating how many smaller numbers there are and delete the oldest number.

Which algorithm should I use? I would like to optimize for making the calculation fast as it's not the only thing that calculated on those 100 ms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For practical reasons and reasonable values of `n` you're best of with a **ring-buffer** of primitive `int`s (to keep track of oldest entry), and a **linear scan** for determining how many values are smaller than `x`.

In order for this to be in `O(log n)` you would have to use something like [Guavas TreeMultiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html). Here is an outline of how it would look.

```
class Statistics {

    private final static int N = 180;
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    SortedMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public int insertAndGetSmallerCount(int x) {

        queue.add(x);                                // O(1)
        counts.put(x, getCount(x) + 1);              // O(log N)

        int lessCount = 0;                           // O(N), unfortunately
        for (int i : counts.headMap(x).values())     // use Guavas TreeMultiset
            lessCount += i;                          // for O(log n)

        if (queue.size() > N) {                      // O(1)
            int oldest = queue.remove();             // O(1)
            int newCount = getCount(oldest) - 1;     // O(log N)
            if (newCount == 0)
                counts.remove(oldest);               // O(log N)
            else
                counts.put(oldest, newCount);        // O(log N)
        }

        return lessCount;
    }

    private int getCount(int x) {
        return counts.containsKey(x) ? counts.get(x) : 0;
    }

}
```

On my 1.8 GHz laptop, this solution performs 1,000,000 iterations on about 13 seconds (i.e. one iteration takes about 0.013 ms, well under 100 ms).

Comment: Since there are only 180 numbers and recalculation only occurs every 100ms I'd definitely optimize for readability and not for speed.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I don't think it would be more readable with a list. Besides, who says 180 is cast in stone? ;)

Comment: @Eiko, yeah, especially in the form of a graph, with `n` increasing along the x-axis ;-)

Comment: I did some performance tests on the 180 case - inserted 1 millon entries: Queue+Tree 1380 ms, Queue alone: 1300 ms, plain int[] ring buffer: 210 ms.

Comment: @Eiko, now repeat the tests with larger and larger value for `n` :-)

Comment: Besides performance difficulties, _TreeSet_ will have a problem with repeating numbers. (Although, you could certainly use STL's multiset, sacrificing some more performance. Not sure if multiset provides ordering, though)

Comment: I think the sorted.headSet.size is O(N) and not O(log N). The number of returned elements  is random so in average N/2. counting N/2 elements is O(N).

Comment: You'd better to remove zeroes from _counts_ map, if you don't want it to contain million elements after million iterfations.  +1 for dedication, though :)  I think you proved that whoever wants to solve this in O(logn) efficiently is better to write his own container.

Comment: @aioobe: Have you tried to time the vanilla version (I mean without the TreeMap). Your code could be easily modified to do so and that will be interesting to compare the time.

Comment: @Nikita, good point again. Thought at first that it wouldn't matter, but I realize it does, if the OP has a large spread of input numbers.

Comment: @mp14, you mean with a ring-buffer? Not as fun to write, as it's obvious that it won't scale as well for large `N`.

Comment: @aioobe: no just count from the queue (and remove all the TreeMap things). O(N) I know but as N is low that might be faster (if you remove all the sorting overhead)

Comment: @aioobe: event if it's 'obvious' , it's still interesting to see when (I mean for which value of N) the optimized version is faster. You might be surprised. (anyway I m not speak of a ring-buffer  but count from a linked list)

Answer (score 6):

You can keep an array of 180 numbers and save an index to the oldest one so that when a new number comes in you overwrite the number at the *oldest* index and increment the index modulo 180 (it's a bit more complex than that since you need special behaviour for the first 180 numbers).

As for calculating how many numbers are smaller I would use the brute force way (iterate all the numbers and count).

---

**Edit:** I find it funny to see that the [*"optimized"* version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965986/calculating-percentiles-on-the-fly/3966298#3966298) runs five times slower than this trivial implementation (thanks to [@Eiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356292/eiko) for the analysis). I think this is due to the fact that when you use trees and maps you lose data locality and have many more memory faults (not to mention memory allocation and garbage collection).

Comment: +1. A ring buffer beats ArrayList and LinkedList. And full iteration to get the percentile seems not too bad either.

Comment: But his cache should hold only 180 (+1) numbers anyway.

Comment: @Eiko, I don't get your point the cache holds 180 elements as described in the question and the +1 is the parameter.

Comment: Ah, sorry... didn't catch the ring buffer. I thought you wanted to keep the age of each element.

Comment: @Motti, regarding your edit, I find it interesting that the problem *can* be solved in *O(log n)*. Unfortunately however, I've become hopelessly theoretical. I guess it's an occupational injury after a few years of graduate studies in formal methods :-\

Comment: There is nothing surprising about the fact that a theoretically better algorithm might perform slower on small datasets.

Comment: @Moron, I agree which makes the premature optimization even worse

Comment: @Motti: Premature optimization isn't the term I will use for aioobe's solution!

Comment: @Motti: Well I would say it is a different choice of algorithm/design rather than premature optimization! Picking the right algorithm depends on a lot of factors not available to us. For instance OP might have said n=180, but is that 100% guaranteed? What systems will it run on? For instance you might benchmark your solutions all you want, but it does not really matter till OP actually does it on systems he expects it to be running on. Calling it premature optimization is just wrong and well... premature.

Answer (score 3):

Add your numbers to a list. If size > 180, remove the first number. 
Counting is just iterating over the 180 elements which is probably fast enough. It's hard to beat performance wise.

Comment: Nice and simple :) For such small arrays being O(n) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LinkedList implementation.

With this structure, you can easily manipulate the first and the last elements of the List.
 (addFirst, removeFirst, ...)
For the algorithm (find how many numbers are lower/greater), a simple loop on the list is enough, and will give you the result in less than 100ms on a 180's element list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a custom linked list data structure where each node maintains next/prev as well as sorted next/prev references. Then inserting becomes a two phase process, first always insert node at tail, and the insert sort, and the insert sort will return the count of numbers less than x. Deleting is simply removing the head.

Here is an example, NOTE: THIS IS *VERY NASTY* JAVA, IT IS EXAMPLE CODE TO PURELY DEMONSTRATE THE IDEA. You get the idea! ;) Also, I'm only adding a few items, but it should give you an idea of how it would work... The worst case for this is a full iteration through the sorted linked list - which is no worse than the examples above I guess?

```
import java.util.*;

class SortedLinkedList {

  public static class SortedLL<T>
  {
    public class SortedNode<T>
    {
      public SortedNode(T value)
      {
        _value = value;
      }

      T _value;

      SortedNode<T> prev;
      SortedNode<T> next;

      SortedNode<T> sortedPrev;
      SortedNode<T> sortedNext;
    }

    public SortedLL(Comparator comp)
    {
      _comp = comp;
      _head = new SortedNode<T>(null);
      _tail = new SortedNode<T>(null);
      // Setup the pointers
      _head.next = _tail;
      _tail.prev = _head;
      _head.sortedNext = _tail;
      _tail.sortedPrev = _head;
      _sortedHead = _head;
      _sortedTail = _tail;      
    }

    int insert(T value)
    {
      SortedNode<T> nn = new SortedNode<T>(value);

      // always add node at end
      nn.prev = _tail.prev;
      nn.prev.next = nn;
      nn.next = _tail;
      _tail.prev = nn;

      // now second insert sort through..
      int count = 0;
      SortedNode<T> ptr = _sortedHead.sortedNext;
      while(ptr.sortedNext != null)
      {
        if (_comp.compare(ptr._value, nn._value) >= 0)
        {
          break;
        }
        ++count;
        ptr = ptr.sortedNext;
      }  

      // update the sorted pointers..
      nn.sortedNext = ptr;
      nn.sortedPrev = ptr.sortedPrev;
      if (nn.sortedPrev != null)
        nn.sortedPrev.sortedNext = nn;
      ptr.sortedPrev = nn;

      return count;            
    }

    void trim()
    {
      // Remove from the head...
      if (_head.next != _tail)
      {
        // trim.
        SortedNode<T> tmp = _head.next;
        _head.next = tmp.next;
        _head.next.prev = _head;

        // Now updated the sorted list
        if (tmp.sortedPrev != null)
        {
          tmp.sortedPrev.sortedNext = tmp.sortedNext;
        }
        if (tmp.sortedNext != null)
        {
          tmp.sortedNext.sortedPrev = tmp.sortedPrev;
        }
      }
    }

    void printList()
    {
      SortedNode<T> ptr = _head.next;
      while (ptr != _tail)
      {
        System.out.println("node: v: " + ptr._value);
        ptr = ptr.next;
      }      
    }

    void printSorted()
    {
      SortedNode<T> ptr = _sortedHead.sortedNext;
      while (ptr != _sortedTail)
      {
        System.out.println("sorted: v: " + ptr._value);
        ptr = ptr.sortedNext;
      }      
    }

    Comparator _comp;

    SortedNode<T> _head;
    SortedNode<T> _tail;    

    SortedNode<T> _sortedHead;
    SortedNode<T> _sortedTail;    

  }

  public static class IntComparator implements Comparator
  {
    public int compare(Object v1, Object v2){
      Integer iv1 = (Integer)v1;
      Integer iv2 = (Integer)v2;
      return iv1.compareTo(iv2);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){

    SortedLL<Integer> ll = new SortedLL<Integer>(new IntComparator());
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(1));
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(3));
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(2));
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(5));
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(4));
    ll.printList();
    ll.printSorted();    

    System.out.println("inserting new value");
    System.out.println("inserting: " + ll.insert(3));
    ll.trim();
    ll.printList();
    ll.printSorted();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the cache be a list, so you can insert at the start and let the oldest be at the end and be removed.

Then after every insertion just scan the whole list and calculate the number you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html) implementation of the [DescriptiveStatistics class](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#DescriptiveStatistics%28int%29) ([Percentile.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/rank/Percentile.java?view=markup))

Comment: As far as I see this class doesn't have a function to forget the oldest value.

Comment: In the DescriptiveStatistics class you can set a "window size".  Javadoc of the addValue() method: Adds the value to the dataset. If the dataset is at the maximum size (i.e., the number of stored elements equals the currently configured windowSize), the first (oldest) element in the dataset is discarded to make room for the new value.
http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#line.150

Answer (score 0):

180 values is not many and a simple array which a brute force search and System.arraycopy() should be faster than 1 micro-second (1/1000 milli-second) and incurs no GC.  It could be faster that playing with more complex collections.

I suggest you keep it simple and measure how long ti takes before assuming you need to optimise it.